# Blank/grey folium map when rendering in Jupyter Notebooks

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, folium, choropleth

everyone. It's my first time here.

I'm trying to create a choropleth map that shows San Francisco's crime rate. I think that the code was just correct but for some reason, the map is not rendering. I can see the zoom buttons, the gauge, and the legend but not the map. I am only seeing a blank grey background. I had this problem with Jupyter Notebooks, Google Colab, and IBM Watson Studio.

Here's the screenshot of the rendered map and the code that I wrote. Behind the image, it tells me to make the notebook Trusted. But I think that the notebook is trusted because I created it (and Jupyter tells it). Some references said that it's because of the browser but the same thing happens in Chrome and Firefox. I tried creating a simple world map (using `world_map = folium.map(); world_map`) but it successfully rendered the world map.

I'm not sure what to do next. Any suggestions will be much appreciated. Thanks.

[rendered map - grey screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JEWV.png)

```
#create pandas dataframe
crime = pd.read_csv('https://cocl.us/sanfran_crime_dataset')
crime.rename({'PdDistrict':'Neighborhood'}, axis=1, inplace=True)
crime_neighborhood = crime['Neighborhood'].value_counts().to_frame()
crime_neighborhood.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True)
crime_neighborhood.rename({'Neighborhood':'Count', 'index':'Neighborhood'}, inplace=True, axis=1)

#import json 
!wget --quiet https://cocl.us/sanfran_geojson/san-francisco.geojson -o san-francisco.geo.json
sanfran_json = r'https://cocl.us/sanfran_geojson/san-francisco.geojson'

#create San Francisco map
sanfran_map = fl.Map(location=[38, 122], zoom_start=12, tiles='Mapbox Bright')

#create Choropleth map
fl.Choropleth(
    geo_data=sanfran_json,
    data=crime_neighborhood,
    columns=['Neighborhood', 'Count'],
    key_on='feature.properties.DISTRICT',
    fill_color='YlOrRd', 
    fill_opacity=0.7, 
    line_opacity=0.2,
    legend_name='San Francisco Crime Rate').add_to(sanfran_map)

#show map
sanfran_map
```

Answer (score 0):

Based from the forums I've read, the issue was because of the Mapbox Bright tile. I don't know the technical explanation but this tile seems to be no longer working in some cases. I'm glad that it's fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution could be the lack of internet connection to the map tile server.

I encountered a gray/blank map because jupyter was using an obsolete version of Chrome, which was blocked by the company internet security policy.  The notebook showed no error message, it’s only when trying to access the tiles directly in another tab (after seeing some hints in Chrome’s developer tools) that I was able to see the internet security policy message.

In my case, switching to a newer version of Chrome fixed the issue.